# Node.js installation wrong version. Why apt install not working correct?

Tags: node.js, linux

I try to install Node.js 6 on my Raspberry Pi. I already searched to web and found a howto, but this is not working for me. What is wrong?

Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster)

```sh
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 6.x LTS Boron repo...

## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
OK:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
OK:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
OK:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x buster InRelease
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig

## Confirming "buster" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/dists/buster/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
OK

## Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 6.x LTS Boron repo...

+ echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x buster main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
+ echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x buster main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

## Running `apt-get update` for you...

+ apt-get update
OK:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
OK:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
OK:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x buster InRelease
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig

## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 6.x LTS Boron and npm
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
     echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

```sh
root@Raspi:/home/pi# apt-get install --yes nodejs

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
AbhÃ¤ngigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benÃ¶tigt:
  gyp libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray libnode-dev libssl-dev libuv1-dev python-pkg-resources
Verwenden Sie Â»apt autoremoveÂ«, um sie zu entfernen.
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
  npm
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  nodejs
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 2 nicht aktualisiert.
Es mÃ¼ssen noch 0 B von 86,5 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 153 kB Plattenplatz zusÃ¤tzlich benutzt.
Vormals nicht ausgewÃ¤hltes Paket nodejs wird gewÃ¤hlt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 51780 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../nodejs_10.15.2~dfsg-2+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Entpacken von nodejs (10.15.2~dfsg-2+rpi1) ...
nodejs (10.15.2~dfsg-2+rpi1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-alternatives: /usr/bin/nodejs wird verwendet, um /usr/bin/js (js) im automatischen Modus bereitzustellen
Trigger fÃ¼r man-db (2.8.5-2) werden verarbeitet ...
```

I already tried with sudo and also as root.

Why it still installing Node.js 10??

Any idea what to do?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the source you are using, hopefully, this page can be of some help -> https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your nodejs tarball from node site e.g. node-v6.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz from v6.11.3

```
wget nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz
```

Unpack provided archive files to /opt/nodejs

```
mkdir -p /opt/nodejs
tar -xvzf node-v8.12.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz -C /opt/nodejs/
```

Create link to current node version

```
cd /opt/nodejs
mv node-v8.12.0-linux-armv7l 8.12.0
ln -s 8.12.0 current
```

Create link to current node binary

```
ln -s /opt/nodejs/current/bin/node /bin/node
```

Verify Node version

```
node -v
```

v8.12.0

Comment: Thx for your help!! I only had to change nodejs version to https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz as raspi has armvcpu. But the rest is working